# A question about the types of parameters or variables in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm using AnyLogic and I want to know if it is possible to have a parameter or a variable with multiple types. For example, if I have Four agents "Factory", "Distributor", "Fulfillment center" and "Order". And, I want to create in "Order" class a parameter or a variable called "Origin" and it can take the type of Distributor or Fulfillment Center in order to know who sent the order to the Factory

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object as the parameter type... but then later you will need to cast that parameter into the proper type.

so when you want to use the Factory properties you would need to do ((Factory)parameter).property

Another option is to make Factory, FullfilmentCenter and Distributor extend from another class called Entity for example and in that case you can also create the parameter of type Entity and do the same I explained above.

You can extend from another agent in the advanced properties of the agent
[image: EXTENDS]

You may also need depending on what you are doing to know if this thing is a factory or a distributor... for that you can do

```
if(parameter instanceof Factory){
    Factory factory=(Factory)parameter;
    ... //now do what you want with your factory local variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But I didn't understand why we should extend from another agent ?

Comment: you don't need to.. it's just an option... you can just use an Object type for your parameter and you don't extend anything.

Comment: I tried this first option and it didn't work because "Distributor" and "Fulfillement center" send orders automatically to "Factory" ( I used "event" in each agent in order to create orders automatically). So there's a case where a "Distributor" and a "Fulfillement center" send at the same time orders to "Factory" so my parameter don't know whether to take the type of  "Distributor" or "Fulfillement center"

Comment: In that case you have severe problems with your logic that have nothing to do with the answer provided here or with your original question.